# Need help styling Google Translate button

Tags: css, styles, google-translate

I'm at a loss for styling the Google Translate button on my website via CSS. Specifically, I want to change the background/text colors from the default white/black to those that will match my page. So far I've tried several methods including those offered in another thread here, but to no avail. I'm using the simple dropdown button, and the HTML code is below. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="float:left; padding-left:15px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ca,da,de,el,en,es,fr,it,ja,ko,nl,pl,pt,ru,sv,tl', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just paste following right after your `<scripts>` tags

```
<style>
    div#google_translate_element div.goog-te-gadget-simple{background-color:green;}
    div#google_translate_element div.goog-te-gadget-simple a.goog-te-menu-value span{color:yellow}
    div#google_translate_element div.goog-te-gadget-simple a.goog-te-menu-value span:hover{color:#fff}
</style>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Updated** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pu6M6/1/) **for hover.**

Comment: Also, I should have included this in my objectives for the translate button, but I am also trying to add a text hover effect (color change). I tried duplicating the 2nd line of code you provided and adding "a:hover{color:#ffffff}" at the end, but no success there. Any solutions to this as well? Thanks again!

Comment: Aha, "span:hover"! Thank you again!

Comment: Any ideas on how to change the dropdown menu's colors? The blue background on hover really clashes with my website.

Answer (score 1):

Default styling by jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#google_translate_element').on("click", function () {

        // Change font family and color
        $("iframe").contents().find(".goog-te-menu2-item div, .goog-te-menu2-item:link div, .goog-te-menu2-item:visited div, .goog-te-menu2-item:active div, .goog-te-menu2 *")
            .css({
                'color': '#687074',
                'font-family': 'tahoma'
            });

        // Change hover effects
        $("iframe").contents().find(".goog-te-menu2-item div").hover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#18BA9B').find('span.text').css('color', 'white');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white').find('span.text').css('color', '#687074');
        });

        // Change Google's default blue border
        $("iframe").contents().find('.goog-te-menu2').css('border', '1px solid #18BA9B');

        // Change the iframe's box shadow
        $(".goog-te-menu-frame").css({
            '-moz-box-shadow': '0 3px 8px 2px #666666',
            '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 3px 8px 2px #666',
            'box-shadow': '0 3px 8px 2px #666'
        });
    });
});
```